# Style when indenting a wrapped, parenthesized if condition

Tags: python, coding-style

Say I have the function

```
def func(arg1):
    if (arg1 > 5
        and arg1 != 10):
        return "something"
```

What do I do about the fact that `if (` is 4 characters long, thus making the "return" bit look odd (and potentially misleading)? Please don't say put the `if` contents on 1 line, in my actual code the contents are longer than 79 characters.

I have thought of a couple of options:

A)

```
def func(arg1):
    if (arg1 > 5
        and arg1 != 10
        ):
        return "something"
```

B)

```
def func(arg1):
    if (
        arg1 > 5
        and arg1 != 10
    ):
        return "something"
```

Off-topic, but the orphaned  `):` looks like an unhappy face :(

Comment: not answering your question, but If you have >80 characters inside of your `if` condition, then you may consider to extract parts of it into several local variables or replace with boolean function call. Not to avoid solving indentation problem, but to improve readability.

Comment: I highly recommend option B.  It is the only option that makes it clear that the indentation inside the `if` condition is separate and not semantically connected to the indentation of the `if` body.

Comment: @BrenBarn It seems everyone has their own favourite style :S

Comment: @RomanI Useful tip, but I think in the specific case in my actual code, readability would be reduced (the corresponding arg1 and 5 have longish variable names, basically)

Comment: Actually, do loop statements and functions follow the same style guidelines?

Comment: What is wrong with that unhappy face? I do it all the time. In my Python code, I mean. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEP 8 recommends a double-indent in similar cases](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), and I think it looks fine:

```
def func(arg1):
    if (arg1 > 5
            and arg1 != 10):
        return "something"
```

but

> This PEP explicitly takes no position on how or whether to further visually distinguish continuation lines after multi-line `if` statements.

so you can really use any of the acceptable options according to it:

> ```
> # No extra indentation.
> if (this
>     and that):
>     do_something()
>
> # Add a comment, which will provide some distinction in editors
> # supporting syntax highlighting.
> if (this
>     and that):
>     # Since both conditions are true, we can frobnicate.
>     do_something()
>
>
> # Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
> if (this
>         and that):
>     do_something()
> ```

Comment: Ah, must have missed that when I last read it

Comment: PEP8 recommends to make indentation of continued lines distinguishable from the following indented lines. It kind of contradicts itself in the examples you've quoted versus the negative example that comes before (_"Further indentation required as indentation is not distinguishable."_).

Comment: @moooeeeep That's probably why I missed the extra indentation thing, got irritated by the contradiction

Answer (score 1):

PEP8 *does* cover this. This:

```
def func(arg1):
    if (arg1 > 5
        and arg1 != 10):
        return "something"
```

should be formatted like the following, assuming each part is below 80 chars:

```
def func(arg1):
    if arg1 > 5 and arg1 != 10:
        return "something"
```

Or like this, to distinguish control flow code blocks from continuations:

```
def func(arg1):
    if (
      really.really.really.really.really.really.really.long.name(arg1) > 5
      and arg1 != 10):
        return "something"
```

While aligning along parentheses is usually fine, I'll assert that the following is *bad* because it does not visually distinguish between code block and the parenthesis aligned conditionals:

```
def func(arg1):
    if (really.really.really.really.really.really.really.long.name(arg1) > 5 
        and arg1 != 10): # Don't do this!
        return "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain, I know.  In many peoples opinion, PEP8 doesn't quite cover this.  I use Flake8 to check my Python code, and this particular situation is a real visual code-killer.

If you aren't using an automated style checker, I'd stick with your first example:

```
def func(arg1):
    if (arg1 > 5
        and arg1 != 10):
        return "something"
```

Just so you know, this violates [E125 (continuation line with same indent as next logical line)](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes).  If you try to fix it, you will likely run in to [E127 (continuation line over-indented for visual indent)](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes).  It's a viscous cycle ;)

One thing you can do to *fool* the style checker is to create an offset of 1 char and add another indentation level to the conditional code block.  This seems silly, but it will solve all of the PEP8 issues.

```
def func(arg1):
if ((arg1 > 5
     and arg1 != 10)):
        return "something"
```

Admittedly, most of the time I leave those lines longer than 80 characters for your exact reasons (and E125).  You could also refactor your conditional, but I'm not sure it's worth the extra effort.